# Jwplayer quality toggle for wowza vod

Tags: video, jwplayer, wowza

I'm trying to add quality toggel for jwplayer for wowza video on demand (vod) website, but it's not working:

```
<div id='player_preview' style='float:left;'> 
    <video id='video_tag' width='750'height='400' controls autoplay> 
    <source src='video_path/mp4:720_faddi.mp4/playlist.m3u8' type='video/mp4'> 
    </video>
</div> 
<script type='text/javascript'> 
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) &&   navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox/i) ) 
{ document.getElementById('android_firefox').style.display = ''; 
 document.getElementById('video_tag').style.display = 'none'; 
} 

    jwplayer("player_preview").setup({
          image: "/uploads/myPoster.jpg",
          sources: [{
            file: "rtmp://video_path//mp4:720_faddi.mp4",
            label: "720p HD"
          },{
            file: "rtmp://video_path//mp4:480_faddi.mp4",
            label: "480p HD"
          }],
          height: 400, 
          width: 750, 
        });
</script>
```

Is there any other settings for video on demand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved guys

Error was that there is not video.smil file.
I have created it and now it's working.
The video.smil file should be something like this:

```
<smil>
<head>
<meta base="rtmp://server_ip/" />
</head>
<body>
<switch>
  <video src="720_faddi.mp4" height="720" system-bitrate="2000000" width="1280" />
  <video src="360_faddi.mp4" height="360" system-bitrate="800000" width="640" />
  <video src="240_faddi.mp4" height="240" system-bitrate="300000" width="426" />
</switch>
</body>
</smil>
```

And the final code will be like:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/jwplayer.js'></script>
<div id='player_preview' style='float:left;'> 
<video id='video_tag' width='560'height='400' controls autoplay> 
<source src='http://server_ip/vod/smil:example.smil/playlist.m3u8' type='video/mp4'> 

</video> 
</div> 
<script type='text/javascript'> 
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) && navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox/i) ) 
{ document.getElementById('android_firefox').style.display = ''; 
 document.getElementById('video_tag').style.display = 'none'; 
} 
jwplayer('player_preview').setup({ 
playlist: [{ 
  sources: [ 
   {file:'http://server_ip/vod//smil:example.smil/jwplayer.smil',}, 
   {file:'http://server_ip/vod//smil:example.smil/jwplayer.smil/playlist.m3u8'} 
  ] 
 }], 
 height: 400, 
 width: 560, 
 fallback: false, 
 repeat: true, 
 autostart: true, 
 primary: 'flash', 
 stretching: 'uniform' 
 }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Great, glad you got it!